# Django - No Reverse Match Error - URL only works with static values

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django site that displays a list of projects. You go to a page, you see a project, you click it, and you can then see project details and have the option to edit the page.

For each individual project, I use a template called project.html. Then on that page, I have a link to edit_project.html

```
<a href="{% url 'profile:edit_project' project.id %}">Edit Project</a>
```

Whenever I try to load the project page to view, I get this error:

> Reverse for 'edit_project' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1
>   pattern(s) tried: ['edit_project/(?P\d+)/$']

I checked the urls, and they seemed fine. So, I tried hard-coding a project id that I knew was in the database. For example, I called:

```
   <a href="{% url 'profile:edit_project' 5%}">Edit Project</a>
```

instead of calling that same thing with "project.id". When I did that, the error went away.

Why does this work with a hard-coded value instead of a project.id variable?

I also tried deleting the database and all the migrations in case something strange was happening there. I got the same issue though.

Here is the code I used to set everything up in case it is helpful.

**project.html**

```
{% extends "profile/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <p>
        <a href="{% url 'profile:edit_project' project.id %}">Edit Project</a>
    </p>
    <p>Status: {{ status }}</p>

{% endblock content %}
```

**edit_project.html**

```
{% block content %}
    <p><a href="{% url 'profile:project' project.id %}">{{ project }}</a></p>
    <p>Edit project:</p>

    <form action="{% url 'profile:edit_project' project.id %}" method='post'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button name="submit">Save Changes</button>
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def edit_project(request, project_id):
    """Edit an existing project"""
    project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)
    #Make sure the project belongs to the owner
    if project.owner != request.user:
        return Http404
    if request.method != 'POST':
        #Initial request; pre-fill form with the current entry
        form = ProjectForm(instance=project)
    else:
        #POST data submitted; process data
        form = ProjectForm(instance=project, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile:project',args=[project.id]))
    context = {'project':project, 'form':form}
    return render(render, 'profile/edit_project.html', context)
```

**(project) forms.py**

```
 class DateInput(forms.DateTimeInput):
            input_type = 'date'

    class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
            class Meta:
                    model = Project
                    fields = ['name','description','status', 'project_type', 'start_date','end_date', 'due_date']
                    labels = {'name':'Name', 'description':'Description:', 'status':'Status', 'project_type':'Project Type',
                              'start_date':'Start Date', 'end_date':'End Date', 'due_date': 'Due Date',}
                    widgets ={'description':forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols':80}),'start_date':DateInput(),
                              'end_date':DateInput(),'due_date':DateInput()}
```

**urls.py**

```
 urlpatterns = [
        #Home page
        url('^$', views.index, name='index'),

        #Show all projects
        url('projects/$', views.projects, name='projects'),

        #Details for single project
        url('^projects/(?P<project_id>\d+)/$', views.project, name='project'),

        #Page for editing a single project
        url('^edit_project/(?P<project_id>\d+)/$', views.edit_project, name='edit_project'),

    ]
```

Comment: Where is the view that is rendering project.html? Is it passing a `project` variable? The error is showing you that there is no `project.id` in the context.

Comment: I can't believe that. I've fussed over this for about six hours. And I forgot to pass in project to get the id. That worked. Thank you so much.